# Pagination with Instagram REST API. No max_id present

Tags: javascript, pagination, instagram-api

I'm using the Instagram REST API and trying to make a simple paginated profile. According to the [endpoint docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) for `/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` - the request can take a `max_id`... which is supposed to be supplied in the `pagination` object as per "envelope" response [seen here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/). However when I receive my response, the `pagination` object is empty. See response below that I'm getting...

```
{ 
  pagination: {},
  meta: { code: 200 },
  data:[ ... photos ... ]
}
```

I've read other S.O. questions about this and they all claim that "it's empty when there are no more photos" — BUT this is not the case. The account I'm testing with has several hundred photos, and I have no way to get beyond the first 20. I even tried using the `id` of the last object in the `data` array as my `max_id`, but still to no avail.

One other final bit of info I can provide is that my account is still in `Sandbox mode` — don't know if that has anything to do with it (eg: maybe they disable pagination for sandbox accounts).

Anyway, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It's not allowed in Sandbox mode :/
[image]